# Mixing of equal volumes of two ideal gases at constant temperature and pressure in an isolated container

Tags: thermodynamics

"**Mixing of equal volumes of two ideal gases at constant temperature and pressure in an isolated container**"

[image]

In this process why is net work done by the gases $0$ ? If we think about the left hand side container then it expands into a volume of $2V$ from $V$. So the work done must be positive for each of the two ideal gases? Isn't it? Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The system is the separated two gases and a constant total volume container.
The partition is removed and the gases mix by the process of diffusion and there is no work done during this process.
The gases are not doing work on the surroundings ie something outside the container?

Comment: The OP is talking about work done by gas on side one on the other. It is being discussed [here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/54160/jee-preparation) at the moment.

Comment: Your answer is okay. But you didn't get my question correctly it seems. The work done by one gas on another isn't zero. Say if the works are W1 and W2 then $W_1+W_2 \neq 0$. However, the net work done on the system is 0. These two facts just don't match up logically. What am I missing?

Comment: To add to what @Farcher said, gas A is not doing work on gas B.  Their molecules are just gradually switching places as a result of collisions.  Gas B is behaving as if it were gas A.  Just imagine the case where you have gas A in both containers, but in one of the containers, the molecules are radioactively tagged.  So nothing really happens on the macroscale in terms of work.